# Inventory - Calculate Quantity Available for POS

Tags: inventory

From what I have read

Quantity on Hand is the physical number of Items in stock http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/quantity-on-hand.html

Quantity Available is Quantity On Hand minus outbound items (e.g Ordered Quantity)
http://community.intuit.com/posts/quantity-on-hand-vs-quantity-available-2

Does this still hold for POS? Can there be outbound items in POS system since items are picked up immediately?

If not does that mean QtyOnHand = QtyAvailable for POS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in the POS you'd only have Quantity Available.

The WMS (Warehouse Management System) and other systems (like e-commerce and alike) have to have control over Quantity on hand and allocated items in order to stop "overselling" products, but since the POS most often is used at the moment of the sale itself, those controls should already be done with, especially if it is in a physical shop, since the customer obviously holds the item in his/her hand. :)